# Alternative function to paste

Tags: string, r, function

Is there a function that can be an alternative to paste ?
I would like to know if something like this exists in R:

```
> buildString ( "Hi {1}, Have a very nice {2} ! " , c("Tom", "day") )
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

frankc and DWin are right to point you to `sprintf()`.

If for some reason your replacement parts really will be in the form of a vector (i.e. `c("Tom", "day")`), you can use `do.call()` to pass them in to `sprintf()`:

```
string <- "Hi %s, Have a really nice %s!"
vals   <- c("Tom", "day")

do.call(sprintf, as.list(c(string, vals)))
# [1] "Hi Tom, Have a really nice day!"
```

Answer (score 21):

The `sprintf` function is one approach as others have mentioned, here is another approach using the `gsubfn` package:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> who <- "Tom"
> time <- "day"
> fn$paste("Hi $who, have a nice $time")
[1] "Hi Tom, have a nice day"
```

Comment: for fn$paste to work, the variables have to be global variables here , is there any way to use fn$paste with local variables myfunction <- function(X) { fn$paste("Hello $X") } .. I really need something like this :-)

Comment: If you are using the arguments from a function then it seems that the sprintf function would work.  If you want the user to be able to supply the string, but your function has a specific set of variables that they could use, then you can just do a set of calls to gsub (or gsubfn) to substitute possible instance of $who or $time.  This is the approach used by the blockrand package (plot.blockrand function).

Answer (score 19):

I think you are looking for sprintf.

Specifically:

```
sprintf("Hi %s, Have a very nice %s!","Tom","day")
```

Comment: specifically `sprintf("Hi %s, Have a very nice %s!","Tom","day")` (filling in a *vector* of values would be a little bit trickier)

Comment: for what it's worth `sprintf` is in the *See also* section of `?paste` (!!)

Comment: Reading the help files is cheating!

Answer (score 17):

The `whisker` package does this very well, and deserves wider appreciation:

```
require(whisker)
whisker.render ( "Hi {{name}}, Have a very nice {{noun}} ! " , list(name="Tom", noun="day") )
```

Comment: +1, nice function. I assume that the order in the list does not matter? A downside of using this in a package would be that it would introduce a dependency on the whisker package.

Comment: If you are really worried about dependencies you could edit(gsubfn) and save it as a new function. If you are already using stringr you could try this function (http://blog.aboutwilson.net/posts/2014-04/string-interpolation-in-r/) whose purpose matches your intent precisely.

Answer (score 2):

With version 1.1.0 (CRAN release on 2016-08-19), the `stringr` package has gained a string interpolation function `str_interp()`.

With `str_interp()` the following use cases are possible:

**Variables defined in the environment**

```
v1 <- "Tom"
v2 <- "day"
stringr::str_interp("Hi ${v1}, Have a very nice ${v2} !")
#[1] "Hi Tom, Have a very nice day !"
```

**Variables provided in a named list as parameter**

```
stringr::str_interp(
  "Hi ${v1}, Have a very nice ${v2} !",
  list("v1" = "Tom", "v2" = "day"))
#[1] "Hi Tom, Have a very nice day !"
```

**Variables defined in a vector**

```
values <- c("Tom", "day")
stringr::str_interp(
  "Hi ${v1}, Have a very nice ${v2} !",
  setNames(as.list(values), paste0("v", seq_along(values)))
)
#[1] "Hi Tom, Have a very nice day !"
```

Note that the `value` vector can only hold data of one type (a list is more flexible) and the data are inserted in the order they are provided.