# Can a variable be used with / passed to an XPath expression in an Rselenium function?

Tags: r, xpath, rselenium

The Rselenium code below comes from the answer/comment to the [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713466/r-rselenium-navigate-drop-down-menu-list-box-using-id). Sample code is there.

```
option <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//select[@id='main_ddYear']/option[@value='2014']")
option$clickElement()
```

Note the literal '2014' near the end of the first line.

Can a variable be used in place of the literal '2014'? E.g.,

```
var1 = "2014"
option <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//select[@id='main_ddYear']/option[@value= var1 ]")
```

I've tried just using the variable `var1`.

Also tried braces {} inside and outside of single quotes (') `{var1}, '{var1}', {'var1'}`, which were ideas from other posts.

Similarly, I tried using plus signs as suggested in a similar post on how to pass variables to strings in Java. E.g., `+ var1 +, +var+, '+var1+'`.

Comment: You can just paste it. `var1 = "2014"; u <- paste("//select[@id='main_ddYear']/option[@value=",  var1," ]"); option <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', u)`

Comment: whoops, I'm guessing you still need the single quotes so... `u <- paste("//select[@id='main_ddYear']/option[@value=", sQuote(var1)," ]");`

Comment: CSS selectors and XPath are two completely different things. They aren't two names for the same thing. If you're looking for a general term, you're probably thinking of "locator".

Comment: @BoltClock - I meant to insert the CSS expression from the comment in the referenced post  `remDr$findElement("css", "#main_ddYear option[value='2014']")`.   I mistakenly inserted the xpath expression from the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath expression is just a string in [r](/questions/tagged/r), so you should be able to use any [r](/questions/tagged/r) approach for [string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201341/how-can-2-strings-be-concatenated-in-r) or [interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711019/better-string-interpolation-in-r) :

```
var1 = "2014"

option <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', paste("//select[@id='main_ddYear']/option[@value='", var1, "']"))
option <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', sprintf("//select[@id='main_ddYear']/option[@value='%s']", var1))
```

As an aside, it is also possible to compare the value `2014` as number in XPath, by removing the surrounding quotes :

```
option <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', paste("//select[@id='main_ddYear']/option[@value=", var1, "]"))
option <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', sprintf("//select[@id='main_ddYear']/option[@value=%s]", var1))
```

Comment: And for future searchers, the method also works perfectly for `using = css',  along the same lines.