# How to do string interpilation in R

Tags: r, formatting, string-formatting

Basically the function where you add a variable inside a string like the JavaScript template literals:

```js
var str = "This is a sample";

print(`So you load the string in with ${str}, and it would insert the string without going "string" + var + "string" or using the paste() function in r, so I need help`)
```

overall I just need a simple function that would make my life easier with R instead of going like:

```
str <- "STRING"
print(paste("this is very annoying to do to require a", str, "so i need simpler options", sep="", collape=NULL))
```

I tried checking for easy stuff but it takes too long, like

`paste(string1, var, string2, collapse = NULL)` and stuff but its just too annoying and
would be simpler with `str ${var} str`

Comment: The phrase you're looking for is string interpolation. See [Better string interpolation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711019/better-string-interpolation-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `str_glue` is what you're looking for.

```r
library(stringr)
str <- "STRING"
str_glue("when you require a {str}, this is a simpler option")
#> when you require a STRING, this is a simpler option
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>